# I want to integrate a live video viewing feature into my website. Which YouTube API should I use to implement this functionality?

Tags: youtube-api

I want to integrate a live video viewing feature into my website. Which YouTube API should I use to implement this functionality?

I use API :
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search
but I get the execution limit exceeded error.

Can you please suggest me another API?